# Converting nested hashsets into lists (Clojure)

Tags: clojure

I'm a bit new to Clojure and was wondering if anybody can assist me in a problem that is currently confusing me a lot.

I'm trying to convert nested data types, that are currently nested hashmaps, and I want them to be nested lists. See the below example:

```
(def dataset 
  (
   {
    :a #{change to-list}
    :b (foo)
    :c (bar)
   }
   {
    :a #{change to-list}
    :b (foo)
    :c (bar)
   }
  )
)
```

I need to change the data structure storing change to-list, to a list. I've looked for quite a bit to try and get an understanding of how to do this, but so far I'm just puzzled. I've tried playing around with reduce/map, but I can't fully wrap my head around them both so I can't utilize them very well.

Cheers.

Comment: `(map #(update % :a seq) dataset)` should probably work

Comment: Sets implement a seq abstraction. Chances are you don't have to convert it to a concrete list type. Maybe you could explain the context of this problem.

Comment: Thank you leetwinski, that works perfectly.

Comment: @MichielBorkent's comment is obviously correct. If the task is not just for education, you probably don't need any conversion of a set to list. Why would you want to do it?

Comment: To give context, this is a minor hiccup I have hit in a piece of work for University. I'm trying to use a tool that has been made already, that expects a certain data structure to be passed into it, however the data structure needed altering slightly. Or a more concrete explanation, I'm doing AI, and trying to feed a legal move generator, based on STRIPS operators into an A* search. The A* search needed an LMG creating, but the data type that my LMG was generating is incorrect. Interesting though, I'll look into that, I'm not to familiar with the backbones of Clojure.

Comment: Are you saying that it should work feeding a hashset in place of a list though? If so, it might be that I've misdiagnosed my error and barked up the wrong tree for a while. I'm more than happy to learn about all of this though.

Comment: Note that the sample `def` at the top of the post is incorrect, and is the same as `(def dataset nil)`: because your data is not quoted, this definition calls the first map as a function, passing the second as an argument.